# Android Jetpack compose and view model lifecycle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have just started to learn jetpack compose in Android. I saw the view model dependencies available for compose. My question is simple what is the lifecycle of **view model** in compose? For example i created composable function that is presenting the whole screen and i am passing the view model in it. Is this view model depends on composable or activity or fragment life cycle. This is confusing me little or i am on wrong path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short `ViewModel` has its own lifecycle which has `onCleared()` callback which is called when the `LifecycleOwner` of view model get destroyed.

> what is the lifecycle of view model in compose?
> Is this view model depends on composable

No as it depends on its *LifecycleOwner* only and any composable cannot be the *LifecycleOwner* for a *ViewModel* so you can use it with any composable without bothering about its cycle depend on that composable.

> Is this view model depends on activity or fragment life cycle

Actually it depends on its lifecycle owner to clear itselp when the owner got destroyed only. **Activity** or **Fragment** both can be the *LifecycleOwner* for *ViewModel*. For example: if an *ViewModel* is attached to the *Activity* so when the activity get `onDestroy()` then only the viewmodel get destroyed otherwise all the changes the viewmodel can sustain like `onPause()`, `onStop()`, etc.

And that's why the viewmodel is used to sustain configuration changes and you can use it with any *LifecycleOwner* and it will manage its lifecycle at own till the `onCleared()` got called. For more information you can check the document at: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
In compose we have only single activity. It's mean single activity contains multiple view models and all these view models states persist during life cycle of activity.
My question is now we are creating multiple screens using composable all their view models state will remain persist all time in app right ?

Comment: @ZohaibAkram yes all the states states in `ViewModel` will be as it as for the time till `Actviity` is not destroyed as its the `LifecycleOwner` for `ViewModel`.